# How to delete the BBM proxy app and BBM connected app together

Tags: blackberry, bb-messenger

My app is a BBM connected app. It has a proxy app which checks whether the user can continue to our app based on the BBM requirements. The proxy app icon is visible in the BB Os. I have seen that , when the user deletes the proxy app, it doesnt delete my BBM connected app. I would like both the apps to get deleted when the user deletes the proxy app using the BB Menu. I am sure it is possible to achieve this but i dont know how. can any one help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RIM has confirmed this behaviour in OS5 and OS6. This is an OS issue unfortunately so it doesn't have a solution as of yet.